# Throw an exception or just return a string?

Tags: c#, exception

Say I have this function which checks for user details

```
//check valid user's details.
private bool checkUserDatails(String nickname, String groupId)
{
    //check nickname
    if ((nickname == null || nickname.Trim().Equals("")))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //check groupId
    if (groupId == null)
        return false;

    //convert to int
    int id;
    try
    {
        id = int.Parse(groupId);
    }
    catch (Exception) { return false; }

    //check id
    if (id < 0 | id > 100)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

It works great, but the caller function doesn't know why the function returned false if it did. My initial thought was to create my own exceptions such as `IncorrectUsernameException` etc. and throw them. I could also make the return value string and just return "Incorrect username".

What's the correct C# approach to this?

Comment: `if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nickname)) return false;`

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159096/return-magic-value-throw-exception-or-return-false-on-failure

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/j2jensen/exceptions-in-c-done-right-aieyu2jhp

Comment: There are two articles on proper Exception handling I link a lot. They might help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET There are a lot of issues in your code, aside from the part where there are functions for those checks.

Comment: Also: we're missing too much for a full evaluation here. The user details came **from**... somewhere. Wherever that is, you need something to read that info, or parse the info, or create an object. **That** is the place for this code, and the context of that operation will determine what your code should look like. It's also going **TO** somewhere... probably an object. Constructing that object is another place for this code, or perhaps an validation method or property as part of that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Microsoft conventions (in some places, at least), this should look like:

```
private void EnsureValidDetails(string nickname, string groupId)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nickname))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nickname));
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupId))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(groupId));
    }

    int parsedGroupId;

    if (!int.TryParse(groupId, out parsedGroupId))
    {
        // or some better wording
        throw new ArgumentException("GroupId is not a valid number."); 
    }

    if (parsedGroupId < 0 || parsedGroupId > 100)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("GroupId must be between 0 and 100.");
    }
}
```

Notice though, that this method is doing more than it should be doing. `groupId` should be an `int` parameter, and the method should only check for the value to be inside the valid range:

```
private void EnsureValidDetails(string nickname, int groupId)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nickname))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nickname));
    }
    else if (groupId < 0 || groupId > 100)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("GroupId must be between 0 and 100.");
    }
}
```

Yet, this might not be the best way to actually validate this kind of stuff. It certainly works as a generic, framework-independent way, but some .NET frameworks (WPF, WCF, WinForms, ASP.NET) provide built-in ways for doing this.

Comment: This convention is called defensive coding. A method should be defensive about what you give them. So it should rasies an error by throwing an error when arguments you give them are incorrects.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Huh, so it's called defensive coding... Thanks for that.

Comment: It might help to put a side note in your answer for just change the type of groupId to int at the parameter declaration and no need to parse to int.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I was not completely sure of recommending that, that's why I added the comment at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't throw an exception, as it will probably happen quite often that the value `false` is returned. This would cause a pretty big performance decrease. Instead you could for example use an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum), with values like `correct`, `invalid_nickname`, `invalid_id` and so on.

```
enum CheckUserDetailsResult { correct, invalid_nickname, invalid_id }
```

Alternatively you could provide the message via the out reference like that:

```
private bool checkUserDetails (String nickname, String groupId, out String message)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (nickname))
    {
        message = "Invalid nickname!";
        return false;
    }
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: "it will probably happen quite often that the value false is returned." Please explain from where did you get that information, because the OP never mentioned anything even remotely close to that. Out references? You should look at some c# guidelines. The `out` keyword must be used when needed, not for returning messages

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well it checks user details, which probably were entered by the user. And generally, you can't assume users always to make correct inputs, hence it'll probably happen quite often that the user details are invalid.